# Time delay in python

Tags: python

How do I make something have a small delay in python?

I want to display something 3 seconds after afterwards and then let the user input something.

Here is what I have

```
print "Think of a number between 1 and 100"
print "Then I shall guess the number"
```

I want a delay here

```
print "I guess", computerguess
raw_input ("Is it lower or higher?")
```

Comment: No? I'm new, but thanks for the link

Comment: It definitely is an exact duplicate. My comment was auto-posted when I voted to close as a duplicate, it wasn't a question. It just means your question has already been answered.

Comment: Hi bradymat, welcome to SO. Don't be disheartened if this question is closed as a duplicate - we try to keep a single authoritative question/answer for each problem. It's nothing personal, just that it's a common question. If you'd googled your question title, the first result is the question this has been marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: I understand it is a similar topic

Comment: @bradymat A duplicate on SO doesn't mean that the question is exactly the same, rather that the answer to one question answers yours. There is no need to have multiple questions that all have the same answer, so we consolidate them like this. Your question is answered perfectly by the linked question. In future, before you ask a question, it's best to search for an answer using google or the search function - it's faster than posting a duplicate like this, and easier for everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
import time
print "Think of a number between 1 and 100"
print "Then I shall guess the number"

time.sleep(3)

print "I guess", computerguess
raw_input ("Is it lower or higher?")
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Lavender this is exactly what I needed, I shall accept this answer when I am able to do so in 7 minutes time, this answer is phenomenally worded, the spacing is what sets it apart from the others

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import time

print "Think of a number between 1 and 100"
print "Then I shall guess the number"

time.sleep(3)

print "I guess", computerguess
raw_input ("Is it lower or higher?")
```

The number `3` indicates the number of seconds to pause. Read [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html).

Comment: Thank you Mr user1775603 but the lack of spacing makes it harder for me to decipher exactly what is going on between the lines of code I have provided in the question.

Comment: You have very delicate eyes Mr bradymat

Answer (score 2):

```
    import time

    print "Think of a number between 1 and 100"
    print "Then I shall guess the number"

    time.sleep(3) 

    print "I guess", computerguess
    raw_input ("Is it lower or higher?")
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Bowersox but you are missing a quotation mark after "Then I shall guess the number, so I shall not be accepting this answer, sorry

Comment: @bradymat sorry about that it was a bad cut and paste job, I updated.

Comment: It's a trivial answer, of course they are going to be the same. There was really no need for **anyone** to answer, as the question is a duplicate (of a duplicate, no less).

Comment: @Zenith My answer was posted seconds after the first one, after which the first answer was edited to include the import, which my included from the onset.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Sorry, I meant the one posted after your answer

Comment: Thank you Mr Bowersox I shall up vote this answer when I get the required 15 reputation, you are a very helpful fellow

Comment: @bradymat Glad I could help.  Good luck with your script.